# date $match in aggregate function in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to write a query with a $match(where) condition in mongo db. I do not have any option to match only a date here.
The query is below

```
db.LockContentAccess.aggregate([
                            {$match : {AccessDate:{$eq : new Date()}}},
                            {"$project" : 
                                     { .... }
                            }
                              ]);
```

Here the problem is I have no option to match only the date part like sql queries (not the time).

Can any one help me, please?

Comment: What is the value of `AccessDate` in your documents? Is it a MongoDate Object or string? Does it hold the time or just YYYYMMDD?

Answer (score 4):

The classname `Date` is a bit misleading, because it represents not just a calendar day but also includes the time, accurate to the millisecond. So when you query them with `$eq : new Date()` you will only get the documents which have a date-field with this millisecond. When you want the documents of a whole day, there are three possible workarounds.

1. When you only need dates with day-precision anyway, truncate the date in your documents to midnight by setting the time to `0:00:00.000`. When you query for a date, create a new Date object which also has the time set to `0:00:00.000`.
2. Query a range of dates with `$gte: [todays date with time 0:00:00.000]` and `$lte [todays date with time 23:59:59.999]`. This is what I would recommend you to do, because it retains the exact time in case you need it for another use-case.
3. Ditch the whole inbuilt Date handling stuff and store your dates as an integer representing days elapsed since a specific date in the past. I would not recommend this, but when you are sure you don't need any of [the special features MongoDB offers for date handling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/), it is an option.

How to change the time of a `new Date()` object depends on what programming language you use.